# Android: what is the purpose of writing (EditText) or (TextView) after the equal sign when initializing a widget

Tags: java, android

I've just recently started learning how to develop an app and I'm also fairly new to java so this question might sound a little bit silly. When initializing a button or any other widget i've seen that most tutorials use a code line similar to this `Button TranslateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TranslateBtn);` however when i tried to run my code like this `Button TranslateBtn = findViewById(R.id.TranslateBtn);` It had also worked the same way. however my code was fairly simple which is why I'm curious to know if the brackets had another functionality that helped with more complex code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For android, `findViewById` returns a `View`. basically all UI components are of type `View`. to get the properties of a `Button` we have to cast the result of `findViewById` to `Button`

```
Button TranslateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TranslateBtn);
```

this is a (explicit) cast of the `View` with id `TranslateBtn` to a type `Button`.

However, this is now outdated and no longer needed

```
 Button TranslateBtn = findViewById(R.id.TranslateBtn);
```

is also valid.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) for some more official info, specifically:

> In most cases -- depending on compiler support -- the resulting view
>   is automatically cast to the target class type. If the target class
>   type is unconstrained, an explicit cast may be necessary.

hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Well a few years ago you could not write

```
Button TranslateBtn = findViewById(R.id.TranslateBtn);
```

Because `findViewById` returned only `View`, that you had to cast manually. Now you can avoid useless cast because `findViewById` returns generic `<T extends View>`.

Guess some people still have old habit.